# Why I'm seeing two different IPv4 adresses on Android but same IPv6 address?

Tags: android, linux, networking, ip

I just checked my IPv4 and IPv6 adress of my Android 10 smartphone under Settings->System->About->Status.
Then I opened Chrome and checked my public IP using 'whats my IP'.
IPv4 is different.But IPv6 is same.
How this is possible?
I'm using cellular internet connection.

Comment: Questions about topics other than development or programming, but related to Android, are not on-topic for Stack Overflow, but **may** be on-topic at https://android.stackexchange.com (and you're more likely to get a good answer there). Please review [the guidelines for posting in that community](//android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before posting there to ensure that your question is on-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One is of your phone other one is Ip of the router you are connecting via your internet provider

Comment: @ Vojin Puriç So how come ipv6 is same? It also should be different ri8?